# Differentiate between « ils ont » and « ils sont » in oral French

Tags: prononciation

How would I identify if another person is saying / How should I pronounce *ils ont* or *ils sont*?

For example:

> Ils sont des rois. (They are the kings)
>
> Ils ont des rois. (They have the kings)

Answer (score 4):

> Ils sont des rois

is pronounced with an S like in *snakes*, but

> Ils ont des rois

is pronounced like a Z, like in *maze*. When doing the link between two words in french, if the last letter is an "s", the sound will always be "z".

Comment: Your last sentence is not accurate enough and could then be misleading. It is only valid when the starting letter of the following word is a vowel and even then there's quite a lot of examples where you don't use the "z" sound. For example "Tu parles aux animaux". As a matter of fact it is very hard to find a rule with no exception in French so using "always" when stating a rule is hard :-)

Comment: Laurent S. That's why I said "when doing the link between two words". In "Tu parles aux", there's no link.

Comment: Wouldn't the word *os* be an exception?

Answer (score 0):

First things first,

> Ils sont des rois

This is not a very correct way of putting it. You should prefer:

> Ce sont des rois

Now, you do have a point. How could you differentiate:

> Ils sont pris au piège (they are trapped)
>
> Ils ont pris au piège des lapins (they trapped some rabbits)

As said by Lyzvaleska, the first indice is the `z` sound when pronouncing: `Il'z ont`. *Ils* will always connect to the following vowel if there is one.

But another tips is the **complement d'object direct** (*les lapins*) which is required when using *Ils ont* and absent when using *Ils sont*.